# #define F(a) typeof(a) ## _f(a)

Tags: c, gcc, clang

Возможно ли в принципе используя хоть какие-нибудь builtin_расширения компилятора (gcc || clang), или самого языка (_Generic || ?), или еще какую сатанинскую хрень провести конкатенацию идентификатора типа объекта, с произвольной лексемой на стадии +/- препроцессора?
Что бы получить нечто такое:

```
#define F(x) typeof(x) ## _F(x)
Vec2 v={13,66};
F(v); // >>> Vec2_F(v);
```

Comment: В самом деле интересно, как это сделать. Если бы не изначальная порочность самой идеи абстракции (более конкретно, тут моделирования overloading) на нижнем уровне при программировании на Си.

Comment: Надежда только на какое-то феерично-модернистичное расширение компилятора. я перерыл документацию GCC, и ничего подходящего не нашел (хотя там такая камасутра есть, что всякий пайтон позовидует).

Comment: Чем вас не устраивает "ручной контроль" выбора вызываемеой функции? Если хотите автоматизации пишите на крестах

Comment: На деле использую ручной контрль. Но хотелось бы узнать имеется ли принципиальная возможность уйти от этого подхода. 
А на крестах мне не по масти писать.

Comment: Ну, у вас `Vec2` это `typedef` для какой-то структуры? Я не помню, распознает ли `_Generic` typedef. В общем, тут надо либо рыть в этом направлении, либо писать `#define F(T, x) T ## _F(x)      ... F(Vec2, v)` (но это лишено смысла, можно сразу написать Vec2_F(v))

Comment: Если устраивает ограниченный набор типов, то решили здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1115631/Ошибка-при-использовании-generic/1115677#1115677

Comment: Благодарю за подсказку. Узнал для себя что дженерики умеют и кастомные типы обрабатывать (в прочем, тупо было полагать иное). Но это, все же, не решает вопрос. т.к. дженерик отробатывает глубоко после препроцессора. На столько после, что проводить конкатенацию идентефикаторов не получится.
Среди builtin_'ов есть такие функции, которые позволяют реализовать тот же функционал что и дженерик. И, полагаю, что в кишках GCC (и, скорее всего, даже clang) дженерик реализован поверх этих builtin_'ов.