# Ошибка при использовании _Generic

Tags: c, макросы, препроцессор

Навеяно [этим вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1115517/define-fa-typeofa-fa).
Вот есть рабочий код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

#define CHECK_TYPE(X) _Generic((X),    \ 
    int: "int",                        \
    double: "double",                  \
    struct Point: "struct Point"       \
)

int main(void)
{   
    struct Point point;
    printf("%s\n", CHECK_TYPE(1));
    printf("%s\n", CHECK_TYPE(1.1));
    printf("%s\n", CHECK_TYPE(point));

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
int
double
struct Point
```

Теперь немного изменим его:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

#define F(X) _Generic((X),    \
    int: int_F(X),            \
    double: double_F(X),      \
    struct Point: point_F(X)  \
)

void int_F(int v)
{
    printf("Hello int!\n");
}

void double_F(double v)
{
    printf("Hello double!\n");
}

void point_F(struct Point p)
{
    printf("Hello Point!\n");
}

int main(void) {
    struct Point point;
    F(1);
    F(1.1);
    F(point);

    return 0;
}
```

При попытке компиляции получаем следующие ошибки:

> prog.c: In function ‘main’:
>   prog.c:32:4: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘point_F’
>     F(1);
>       ^
>   prog.c:12:27: note: in definition of macro ‘F’
>        struct Point: point_F(X)  \
>                              ^
>   prog.c:25:27: note: expected ‘struct Point’ but argument is of type ‘int’
>    void point_F(struct Point p)
>                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
>   prog.c:33:4: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘point_F’
>     F(1.1);
>       ^~~
>   prog.c:12:27: note: in definition of macro ‘F’
>        struct Point: point_F(X)  \
>                              ^
>   prog.c:25:27: note: expected ‘struct Point’ but argument is of type ‘double’
>    void point_F(struct Point p)
>                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
>   prog.c:34:4: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘int_F’
>     F(point);
>       ^~~~~
>   prog.c:10:16: note: in definition of macro ‘F’
>        int: int_F(X),            \
>                   ^
>   prog.c:15:16: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘struct Point’
>    void int_F(int v)
>               ~~~~^

Но стоит лишь убрать из `_Generic` часть со `struct Point` и всё начинает работать:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define F(X) _Generic((X),    \
    int: int_F(X),            \
    double: double_F(X)       \
)

void int_F(int v)
{
    printf("Hello int!\n");
}

void double_F(double v)
{
    printf("Hello double!\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    F(1);
    F(1.1);

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
Hello int!
Hello double!
```

Вопрос: В чём ошибка? Почему в первом случае `_Generic` спокойно обрабатывет `struct Point`, а во втором случае нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ навеялся читая :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53590497/using-generic-type-in-c-for-function-overloading-in-a-nested-structure

Синтаксис у вас неправильный.

```
# define F( X ) _Generic((X),    \
    int : int_F ,            \
    double : double_F ,      \
    struct Point : point_F  )(X)
```

так пашет.